# Calling on a newly create class

Tags: jquery, html

Was just messing around, and I know why this doesn't work, but I don't see any other way to do it...

Simple function :

```
$(".click").on("click", function() {
    alert("first click");
    $(this).removeClass("click");
    $(this).addClass("next");
});
$(".next").on("click", function(){
    alert("second click");
});
```

however, I always get the "first click" alert. So I know this is because when the page is created the `next` class is not there...

What would be a good way around this?

Here is my test fiddle :

### http://jsfiddle.net/tUp9R/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use event delegation: http://jsfiddle.net/tUp9R/4/

jQuery documentation: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Javascript:

```
$(".test").on("click", ".click", function() {
    alert("first click");
    $(this).removeClass("click");
    $(this).addClass("next");
});

$(".test").on("click", ".next", function() {
    alert("second click");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    <button class="click">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

You could also simplify it a bit by using event data like so: http://jsfiddle.net/tUp9R/7/

```
$(".click").on("click", {first: true}, function(e) {
    if (e.data.first) {
        alert("first!")
        e.data.first = false
    } else {
        alert("not first :)")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can apply **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** syntax using **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** here:

```
$(document).on("click", '.click',function(){
    alert("first click");
    $(this).removeClass("click");
    $(this).addClass("next");
});

$(document).on("click", '.next',function(){
    alert("second click");
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tUp9R/3/)**

Answer (score -1):

add this after $(this).addClass('next').click();
and move the .next click function at the begining so the browser knows what to do when
the function is called.

here's the complete code.

```
`$(".next").on("click", function(){
alert("second click");
});
$(".click").on("click", function() {
alert("first click");
$(this).removeClass("click");
$(this).addClass("next").click();
});`
```